# NGRX Store changing

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have initial State

```html
export const initialState: State = {
    activeStep: 0
};
```

And Reducer

```html
export function reducer(
    state: State = initialState,
    action: SignUpActions
): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SignUpActionType.SET_ACTIVE_STEP:
            return {
                ...state,
                activeStep: action.payload
            };
    }
}
```

In Effect i fire an action to change State data like this:

```html
@Effect()
    error$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<Error>(SignUpActionType.ERROR),
        switchMap((action) => this.responseErrorDialog(action.payload)),
        map((res) => {
            return new SetActiveStep(0);
        })
    );
```

And Subscribe on this part Store in a component

```html
this.store.pipe(select(getActiveStep)).subscribe((step: number) => {
            if (step) {
                ...do some stuff
            }
});
```

**The problem is that subscription in a component dont react on varible changing**

**I think because new value of the State equals the previus step, but i need to react on every changin of a Store**

**How can i do this?**

Comment: add your `getActiveStep` selector code

Comment: @Aravind of corse i did it, i fogot to pin it here

Comment: I'm not able to see that?

Answer (score 0):

The active step remains `0` - a selector won't execute if the state remains the same because they are memoized - see the [NgRx docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors).

Alex Okrushko gave a talk about this concept and how to tweak it to your needs last year [NgRx: Selectors are more powerful than you think](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7GKnjGCXzU)